# In Karaf OSGI Bundle is in Resolved state but Diag shows nothing

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, apache-felix, equinox

We have KARAF based OSGI application. We have 100 bundles which is part of a feature.xml , when we install this feature there is one particular bundle which is always in resolved state we have to manually start this bundle and it is active state. We have checked the bundle:diag but it does not show anything. We add added logs in bind and active method but they are not invoked.

what could be a reason that bundle is in resolved state but not started

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the bundle has an activator at all? Maybe it is not started as there is no BundleActivator and so it makes no difference if it is started or not.

Comment: When i manually started it got started , the bundle does have bundle activator . It looks to me that there are some bundles which are triggering refresh causing this bundle to somehow stuck in resolved state

Answer (score 0):

We actually found the reason for this behavior , this will happen when activate method of one of the service is stuck on some condition , it was actually calling a 3PP code during activation which got stuck on monitor some bug in 3PP . We have fixed that logic